# Find the sum of each row in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to Sheets and I don't know any terminology yet so I wasn't sure how to look this up.
If I have:

```
A1[=SUM(B1:1)]
```

How do I automatically copy that to A2 so that:

```
A2[=SUM(B2:2)]
```

And the same thing continues either indefinitely or until I declare a stopping point?

Comment: P.S. I'm using the mobile app at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you simply copy-paste the formula from A1 to A2 (or several cells below), it will automatically change as you want. This is how *relative references* work.

But it's also possible to get all the sums with one formula. 
The following formula, entered in A1, will create sums of the first seven row in column A. To change the number of rows summed, replace 7 in `B1:7` with another number.

```
=arrayformula(mmult(B1:7 + 0, transpose(B1:1 * 0 + 1)))
```

Explanation:

- `B1:7 + 0` coerces the entries to numbers (so that blank cells become 0).
- `transpose(B1:1 * 0 + 1)` creates a column vector of 1s of suitable size.
- matrix multiplication `mmult` by a column of 1s amounts to summing each row.
- the wrapper `arrayformula` indicates that  the operations are to be done on arrays.

Comment: Very nice formula!