# Using ArrayFormula with CountIF and IsBlank

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Form that asks a series of Yes/No questions. I'm trying to sum the number of Yes responses in each row as a new submission is entered.

[image]

Here's what I have, that doesn't work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(E$2:E),"",(COUNTIF(A2:D2,"yes"))))
```

It works for one cell if I remove isBlank, and just do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:D2,"yes"))
```

But then I've lost the benefit of using "isBlank" to autopopulate for new form submissions. I'm really trying to avoid doing this with hidden sheets.

Comment: What error are you getting? It seems E2:E has nothing but the formula and creating a circular ref error. Your screenshot doesn't show E column. And where (which column) do you enter the formula?

Comment: yes, it's a circular ref error. there's nothing in the E column except the formula entered on E2. I had entered "Yes Count" for E1

Answer (score 1):

In E1 try this formula

```
={"Count";arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), mmult(--(B2:D="Yes"), transpose(B1:D1^0)),))}
```

Change range to suit.

Comment: That's it! Sample formula for this trick was suggested by (currently deleted) user3717023 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262525/find-the-sum-of-each-row-in-a-spreadsheet

Comment: That produces !Value errors, with this message "Function POWER parameter 1 expects number values. But 'Question 2' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
"

Comment: I think he just missed `COLUMN(B1:D1)^0`

Comment: @TimmyD: did you change the range?  Make sure NOT to include the header row .

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((IF(A2:A<>"",MMULT(--(A2:D="yes"),ROW(A1:A4)^0),"")))
```