# Is there a way to use an array formula to keep my formula (to add specific columns) when rows are inserted?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm setting up a spreadsheet that has specific columns summed in each row, but I need the formula to be included when a row is inserted.

The current formula also includes a statement to make a 0 value, if a check box is checked in the last column:

```
=IF(T2=FALSE, SUM(I2,K2,L2,M2,N2,O2), 0)
```

Is there a way I can do this using an array formula?

Comment: It should be possible. Can we assume that column J is empty, or do you need to exclude it from the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula which will give a sum for columns I to O in each row, ignoring column J:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(I2:I="","",if(T2:T<>FALSE,0,I2:I+sumif(row(K2:O)+0*column(K2:O),row(K2:O),K2:O))))
```

but this assumes all rows that have data will have a number in column I.

If this isn't the case, you could go on to test columns individually like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if((I2:I="")*(K2:K=""),"",if(T2:T<>FALSE,0,I2:I+sumif(row(K2:O)+0*column(K2:O),row(K2:O),K2:O))))
```

and so on up to column O if necessary, or maybe column T is always completed and you could test that - it depends how your data actually looks.

[image]

**Note 1**

```
row(K2:O)+0*column(K2:O)
```

is necessary to generate an array which is has the same dimensions as K2:O as required by SUMIF.

**Note 2**

There's also the MMULT approach to getting the row sums [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262525/find-the-sum-of-each-row-in-a-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

```
={"AAA"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(T2:T), IF(T2:T=FALSE, I2:I+K2:K+L2:L+M2:M+N2:N+O2:O, 0), ))}
```

[image: 0]